# Copying files in Linux keeps full path

Tags: linux, backup, directory, cp

I made a script to, every 6 hours, copy a folder to a backup folder, then put them in `/var/www/html/backup/`.

My command to copy the files was `cp -vR ~/world ~/backups/Backup\ on\ $date/world`

My desired result was for each backup to become a folder, and for one folder to be inside it, called `world`, which is copied from my home folder.

Instead, my command kept the full path of the folder. This meant that the the folder structure of the backup ended up being:

`Backup on 5-3-2019
 ↳ home
   ↳ elijahmc
     ↳ backups
       ↳ Backup on 5-3-2019
         ↳ world`

To try to fix this, I changed the arguments from `cp -vR` to `cp -vr`, and this fixed **the folder under `/backups`, but not when I move it to a Zip.**

To recap, I changed `cp -vR` to `cp -vr` and now have this directory structure:

`Backup on 5-3-2019
 ↳ world`

I now turn it into a zip like so:

`rm -f ~/backup.zip` (remove original zip)

`zip -r ~/backup.zip ~/backups/Backup\ on\ $date` (turn new backup into `backup.zip` in root directory

`mv -f ~/backup.zip /var/www/html/backup/` (move `backup.zip` to web server)

Downloading `backup.zip` from the Apache server, the file structure has the same issue as the original command:

`Backup on 5-3-2019
 ↳ home
   ↳ elijahmc
     ↳ backups
       ↳ Backup on 5-3-2019
         ↳ world`

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: What you have posted as the "folder structure" is confusing. Post the actual path instead.

Comment: The change from `cp -vR` to `cp -vr` doesn't make any difference. It's the same command. Tell us the desired path structure for the backup directory and zip. How should we "fix it" if we don't know what you want?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I posted it as a folder structure to show how it only included the specific path, and how it was hierarchical. If you are confused, it created a new folder for each folder in the path.

Comment: @Freddy I added my desired outcome in paragraph 3.

Comment: OK, so what was the actual path, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The broken path ended up being `/backups/Backup on 5-3-2019/home/elijahmc/backups/Backup on 5-3-2019/world`, which is not what I want

Comment: Did you miss typing the tilde, then?

Comment: Yeah, I'd say you should go take a course on Bacula as it'll be easier in the long run

Comment: @MichaelHampton I missed the tilde in the comments, but if you look at the post it is there

Answer (score 1):

1. To copy folder `world` to `~/backups/backup_2019-05-04`:

   ```
   backupdir=~/backups/backup_$(date +%F)
   mkdir -p "$backupdir"
   cp -av ~/world "$backupdir"
   ```

   I used flag `-a` for archive mode which includes `-R`. You don't need to specify `world` in the target argument.
2. To only include the `world` folder in zip file `~/backup_2019-05-04.zip`:

   ```
   cd "$backupdir"
   zip -r ~/backup_$(date +%F).zip *
   ```

   You made the mistake to use the full path to the target directory when you "zipped" the directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it did work for me, but not at first. I thought you were wrong until I realized that `$backupdir` in my `mv` command didn't have the `$` in the start, but after me correcting my error, the local backup worked great. ZIP files now go `backup-**date**/~/backups/backup-on-**date**/world/`.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, I'd say you should go take a course on Bacula as it'll be easier in the long run...but you better learn bash first.

- `~` expands to the value of `$HOME`,
- The `cp` command takes a source (from) and a destination (to) argument;

  - If you want to copy a directory make sure just after `cp` you use `-R` to copy recursively.
- Put that '$date' in a subshell ie `$(date <args>)` so you can get the proper format like `mm-dd-yyyy` there will be more info on that in `man date` or `date --help`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know all of this. I'm not saying that it's copying from the wrong location, it **does** copy the right files, just under a copy of the path. I want it to copy `~/world`, not the entire path with it. I already have a $date variable, I just didn't include it. Do you want the full script?

Comment: Normally `~` expands to the value of `$HOME`, not `/home/`.

Comment: Oh - I see now you put it inside `<` and `>` which have special meaning,  - @leeand00 is correct you need to learn the formatting stuff.

Comment: @Freddy I was using a tablet.  I'll fix it.  You never can tell exactly what character you're typing on a tablet.